# Laravel - nested relationship shows null

Tags: php, laravel

I have a tw-tier nested hasOne relationship and the final relationship appears to be giving null values.

My JobApplication relationship has the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobApplication extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job_applications';
    protected $primaryKey = 'job_application_id';

    public function jobrequest()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Model\JobRequest', 'job_request_id', 'job_request_id');
  }
}
```

My JobRequest Model has the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobRequest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job_requests';
    protected $primaryKey = 'job_request_id';

  public function jobgroup()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Model\JobGroup', 'job_group_code', 'job_group_code');
  }

    public function jobapplication()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\JobApplication', 'job_request_id');
  }
}
```

And my JobGroup has the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;
use Carbon;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobGroup extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job_groups';
    protected $primaryKey = 'job_group_code';

  public function jobrequest()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\JobRequest', 'job_group_code');
  }
}
```

I access them in my controller like so:

```
    $job_applications = JobApplication::with(['jobrequest', 'jobrequest.jobgroup'])
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->first();
```

It queries right on the Debugbar (and yes the query for job_groups gives out data), but when I dumped `$job_applications`, jobgroup shows null

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to eager load it. I can access it like so

```
$job_applications = JobApplication::with('jobrequest')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
dd($job_applications->jobrequest->jobgroup);
```